# Adding percentage product in opencart

Tags: opencart

Please I would like to know if there is a possiblity of adding a products in opencart that are in percentages. Anyone with a possible solution can help out. thanks

Comment: Your question is very un-clear. could you please add more info on what you're trying to make?

Comment: Oh...Here is a clearer version:

Comment: Oh...Here is a clearer version:I want a add product to my site but these product wont have prices attached to them rather they would be in percentage like 50%, 20% such that these "percentage product" can be added to cart as a percentage of what is purchased. I hope I made it clearee now

Comment: are you meaning to imply, that you're selling individual `products` as a part of  `bundle` ?

Comment: Not at all.... I mean a seperate product

Comment: so how do you intend to charge the customers based on percentage?

Comment: Yes...Just some products not all

Comment: So the less that I buy, the cheaper the percentage product? That seems like an anti-marketing scheme.

Answer (score 1):

The best place for this sort of question is the OpenCart forum:
https://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=190